# Wordpress.org Plugin Directory doesn't recognise screenshots

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, readme

I'm a developer and I recently created [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/universal-package-systems-shipping-extension/)

I am not sure what I did wrong but for some reason the icons, screensshots are not being properly displayed.

This is the [readme text](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/universal-package-systems-shipping-extension/trunk/readme.txt).

The developer tutorials hasn't mentioned anything else about handling this so I'm not noticing any error in what I did.

Can you identify what the problem is?

Comment: You'll have to ask someone in the [WordPress support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/). This question is off-topic here.